# How do I test a hit on an equilateral triangle?

Tags: language-agnostic, geometry

I have an equilateral triangle centered at (0,0). The distance between each vertex and the center is 1. What is the math that will let me test if a given coordinate pair falls inside the triangle? I have found examples to do that with arbitrary triangles, but for this very specific case, it seems to me that it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use the general approach here?

Comment: @templatetypedef, aside from elegance, not really.

Answer (score 1):

If one vertice of triangle has (0,1) coordinate (*is it right?*), then point (X,Y) falls inside the triangle when three simple conditions are met together:

```
Y <= 1 + Sqrt(3) * X
Y <= 1 - Sqrt(3) * X
Y >= -1/2
```

or shorter:

```
Y <= 1 - Sqrt(3) * Abs(X)
Y >= -1/2
```